React build config image path css
My config works with "react-scripts": "3.4.3" and refuses to work with "react-scripts": "5.0.1". When building it gives the following error
module.rules[2].oneOf.forEach(({ options, exclude }) => {
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'oneOf' of undefined

I don’t understand what needs to be done to make the problem go away.
The config looks like this:
package.json
{ 
    "name": "react-frontend",   
    "version": "0.1.0",   
    "private": true,   
    "dependencies": {     
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",    
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",     
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",     
        "react": "^18.1.0",     
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0",     
        "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",     
        "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",     
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",     
        "sass": "^1.51.0",     
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"   
    },   
    "scripts": {    
        "start": "react-scripts start",     
        "build": "react-app-rewired build",    
        "test": "react-scripts test",     
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"   
    },   
    "eslintConfig": {     
        "extends": [       
            "react-app",       
            "react-app/jest"     
        ]   
    },  
    "browserslist": {     
        "production": [       
            ">0.2%",       
            "not dead",       
            "not op_mini all"     
        ],     
        "development": [       
            "last 1 chrome version",       
            "last 1 firefox version",       
            "last 1 safari version"     
        ]   
    } 
}

config-overrides.js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    if (env !== 'production') {
        return config;
    }

    const { output, plugins, module } = config;

    output.filename = 'static/js/\[name\].js';

    output.chunkFilename = 'static/js/\[name\].chunk.js';

    const miniCssExtractPlugin = plugins.find(
        (element) =\> element.constructor.name === 'MiniCssExtractPlugin'
    );

    miniCssExtractPlugin.options.filename = 'static/css/\[name\].css';
    miniCssExtractPlugin.options.chunkFilename = 'static/css/\[name\].css';

    module.rules\[2\].oneOf.forEach(({ options, exclude }) =\> {
        if (!options || options.name !== 'static/media/\[name\].\[hash:8\].\[ext\]') {
            return;
        }

        options.name = '[name].[ext]';
        options.outputPath = 'static/media/';

        if (exclude && String(Object.values(exclude)).indexOf('js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx')) {
          // Set public path for media from css
          options.publicPath = '../media/';
        } else {
          // Set public path for media from js
          options.publicPath = 'modules/custom/service_request/sr-forms-react/media';
        }

    });

        return config;
    };

This version works with "react-scripts": "3.4.3", but it doesn't work for me.
I tried different versions of the config and the build starts working, but in the css it does not change the path css of the pictures.
